# oracle instr function pattern search

Tags: oracle

I am newbie to oracle, bit confused with Oracle's Instr Function.
I was searching particular special character formation (not regex pattern) in the clob text.
like example `POS := INSTR(L_STR_DATA, '|^|', 1, 1);` but result giving me position of '|' in the text instead of '|^|',

then I tried to test Instr function with following example.

```
SELECT SYSDATE, INSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE), ':', 1, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

and the result is 0. 
can any one explain.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS',
       INSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),':',1,1)
FROM DUAL
```

Your `TO_CHAR()` on date should have the format for consistent results, as the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (Default date format) may not be same on all sessions.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm):

> The return value is relative to the beginning of string, regardless of the value of position, and is expressed in characters. **If the search is unsuccessful (if substring does not appear occurrence times after the position character of string), then the return value is 0.** *[Emphasis mine]*

There is no ":" character in the string representation of your date.

**EDIT**: So it's not really Oracle's INSTR that you have an issue with, it's actually the fact that the default character representation of your date `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE)` doesn't show the time - only the date.  [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) a reference to Oracle's date formatting.

Comment: but my sysdate gives me "22-Aug-14 11:12:39 AM" in which time section has ":" 
Is it oracle format of time is different than it show ?

Comment: Right, but what does your TO_CHAR(SYSDATE) give you?  Spoiler Alert: no timestamp!